# What is the 64-bit Firefox Beta PPA?

Tags: firefox, 64-bit, ppa

I recently discovered that my computer is 64-bit. I have backed up my Home folder, and reinstalled Ubuntu. The reinstall wasn't *nearly* as painful as I thought.
There is one thing that I can't quite seem to figure out: how do I get the 64-bit Firefox *Beta* build? I **always** get the Beta builds, but I want to take advantage of the 64-bit architecture of my computer. [this page](http://www.libre-software.net/how-to-install-firefox-on-ubuntu-linux-mint) says that Mozilla has come out with a 64-bit version of Firefox, but I can't seem to find it.

I do understand [the ramifications](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2010/01/why-microsoft-isnt-working-on-silverlight-64-bit/) of using a 64-bit browser, but I've decided to jump right in and do it anyway. (Flash and Java are already 64-bit, and who cares about Silverlight, since it's not for Linux anyway?)

There's only one issue, and it's a big one: **I can't find the 64-bit Beta PPA!!!** (I *really* hate using .tar.gz files, but I'd be willing to do that as long as I could still access Firefox via the Launcher. Oh, speaking of which, I don't understand .tar.gz files. Once, I managed to run one (the Dropbox Beta build,) but I have no idea whatsoever on how to *install* them: as in, click on the icon and **go**.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the [official Firefox Beta PPA.](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/firefox-next)

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

---

To add the PPA to your computer, run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Do note that unlike Firefox Nightly builds, you can't use Firefox stable and Firefox Beta releases concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, [Firefox 64 bit](http://nightly.mozilla.org/). It isn't a PPA so you will be compiling it. It is directly from Mozilla.org so you can trust it. I saw another sight that claimed to offer 64 bit Firefox but it looked a little shady. These are also Nightly builds so you can expect some issues. Otherwise this was the only 64 bit Firefox I was able to locate.